# Publish VSCode extension - unauthorized

Tags: plugins, publish, visual-studio-code

I've made a vscode extension, but when I try to publish, I get the unauthorized error.
I've created a Personal access token as described [here](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/tools/vscecli#_publishing-extensions).
I realized that when I select Selected Scopes instead of All Scopes and select all available scopes, some of them stay unchecked after save... I don't know why...
The error message is not self explained "Error: Failed Request: Unauthorized(401) -" with nothing after the "-"...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest to post this and other extension related issues at our GitHub issue tracker: https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues